# PHP Code not Working on Remote Server

Tags: php, web, webserver, remote-server

I am having some trouble with a few lines of PHP code when I upload it to my domain over ftp. The lines below work on my local server on XAMPP but when I upload it to the remote server through my hosting client, instead of echoing out what it is supposed to, I get a blank page with no error log or message displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Code that doesn't work:

```
<?php

function getDominantColour($image, $type='png')
{


    eval('$source = imagecreatefrom' . $type . '("' . $image . '");'); 
    $source_x = imagesx($source); 
    $source_y = imagesy($source); 
    $resized_x = 100; 
    $resized_y = 100; 
    $resized= imagecreatetruecolor($resized_x, $resized_y); 
    imagecopyresampled($resized, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resized_x, $resized_y, $source_x, $source_y);


    $colours = array();
    $rgb = '';
    $index = array();
    for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) 
    {
        for ($y=0; $y<100; $y++)
        {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($resized, $x, $y); 
            $index = imagecolorsforindex($resized, $rgb); 
            $key = 'R' . $index['red'] . 'G' . $index['green'] . 'B' . $index['blue']; 
            if (empty($colours[$key])) 
            {
                $colours[$key] = 1;
            } else { 
                $colours[$key]++;
            }
        }
    }
    arsort($colours, SORT_NUMERIC);
    return key($colours);
}


echo(getDominantColour("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.727404,-74.020862&zoom=50&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue&sensor=false"));

?>
```

Comment: And when you turn on error reporting, what happens then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval is evil *( not always )*. But in your example i would try to avoid it.

In your code you could use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) instead:

```
$source = call_user_func( 'imagecreatefrom' . $type, $image );
```

As if on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php/951868#951868) explained:

> 1. Sometimes eval is the only/the right solution.
> 2. For most cases one should try something else.
> 3. If unsure, goto 2.
> 4. Else, be very, very careful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I changed it so that eval is no longer used but I also learned that the hosting client I have did not have  support for the GD library turned on. These two put together fixed the problem. Thanks so much again for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

eval is banned from lots of servers as a security precaution. Rewrite your code so that you don't use that function.

Comment: Really ? eval function is disabled? been with a ton of hosts, never seen that one. Ahh, I see tons of Free Web Hosts disable this function now, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: How would you recommend that I change the code so that the eval function is not used. Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: @user2484406 can't you just use a switch to decide which `imagecreatefrom` function to call depending on the `type`?

Comment: I changed that since the image will always be a png but it still doesn't work. Is there a specific command or function that wont work on a remote server or hosting client that I used? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script, see what error it gives you.